# Why job doesn't create a pod Kubernetes (Openshift)

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, jobs, kubernetes-cronjob

I created a job using openshift command;

```oc
oc create job <my-job> --from=cronjob/<my-cronjob>
```

, but it doesn't create a pod automatically. I could not find out what is missing here. Probably need to change something on `my-cronjob`'s yaml. So here is the yaml;

```yaml
kind: CronJob
apiVersion: batch/v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: xxx
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: xxx
  resourceVersion: '7504720716'
  name: my-cronjob
  uid: xxxx
  creationTimestamp: '2023-02-17T14:27:25Z'
  generation: 3
  managedFields:
    - manager: helm
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: batch/v1
      time: '2023-04-19T09:06:08Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:meta.helm.sh/release-name': {}
            'f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace': {}
          'f:labels':
            .: {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:concurrencyPolicy': {}
          'f:failedJobsHistoryLimit': {}
          'f:jobTemplate':
            'f:spec':
              'f:template':
                'f:spec':
                  'f:containers':
                    'k:{"name":"my-job"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:envFrom': {}
                      'f:image': {}
                      'f:imagePullPolicy': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:resources':
                        .: {}
                        'f:limits':
                          .: {}
                          'f:cpu': {}
                          'f:ephemeral-storage': {}
                          'f:memory': {}
                        'f:requests':
                          .: {}
                          'f:cpu': {}
                          'f:ephemeral-storage': {}
                          'f:memory': {}
                      'f:terminationMessagePath': {}
                      'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {}
                  'f:dnsPolicy': {}
                  'f:restartPolicy': {}
                  'f:schedulerName': {}
                  'f:securityContext': {}
                  'f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds': {}
          'f:schedule': {}
          'f:successfulJobsHistoryLimit': {}
          'f:suspend': {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: batch/v1
      time: '2023-08-16T08:05:04Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:status':
          'f:lastScheduleTime': {}
      subresource: status
    - manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: batch/v1
      time: '2023-12-05T09:10:40Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:spec':
          'f:jobTemplate':
            'f:spec':
              'f:template':
                'f:spec':
                  'f:containers':
                    'k:{"name":"my-job"}':
                      'f:command': {}
  namespace: ifxbertsearch-staging
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  schedule: 0 1 * * *
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  suspend: true
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: my-job
              image: >-
                xxx
              command:
                - python
                - main.py
                - '49'
              envFrom:
                - configMapRef:
                    name: env-variables
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: '4'
                  ephemeral-storage: 10Mi
                  memory: 5Gi
                requests:
                  cpu: '2'
                  ephemeral-storage: 10Mi
                  memory: 3Gi
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
              imagePullPolicy: Always
          restartPolicy: Never
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          securityContext: {}
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
status: {}
```

So I need to figure out, why the cronjob doesn't create the pod on which the job will be working.

Answer (score 4):

Your CronJob is suspended :

```yaml
spec:
  suspend: true
```

According to [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#schedule-suspension) :

> You can suspend execution of Jobs for a CronJob, by setting the
> optional .spec.suspend field to true. The field defaults to false.
>
> This setting does not affect Jobs that the CronJob has already
> started.
>
> If you do set that field to true, all subsequent executions are
> suspended (they remain scheduled, but the CronJob controller does not
> start the Jobs to run the tasks) until you unsuspend the CronJob.

It also affects any Job created manually from that CronJob, so you need to remove that line in your CronJob ressource :)

Still, you should be able to see `my-job` in the list of Jobs within the concerned namespace, with the same `suspend` attribute.